Перебор значений во многоуровневой HashTables Powershell
Есть некая хэш-таблица. Как перебрать значения и подcтавить номер ip и номер port в URL?
$station = [ordered]@{
    Moskow = @{
        ip = '10.10.10.10'
        UPS1 = '4000'
        UPS2 = '4010'
    }
    NewYork = @{
        ip = '10.10.10.11'
        UPS1 = @{
            ОСНОВНОЙ = '4002'
            РЕЗЕРВНЫЙ = '4013'
        }
        UPS2 = @{
            ОСНОВНОЙ = '4011'
            РЕЗЕРВНЫЙ = '4014'
        }
    }
    London = @{
        ip = '10.10.10.12'
        UPS1 = '4005'
        UPS2 = '4008'
    }
}

IP вставляются, а вот с портами беда. Кто поможет, подскажет?
foreach($item in $station.Values)
{
    $ipaddr = $item.ip
    $arrayport = @($item.UPS1, $item.UPS2, $item.UPS1.'ОСНОВНОЙ', $item.UPS1.'РЕЗЕРВНЫЙ', $item.UPS2.'ОСНОВНОЙ', $item.UPS2.'РЕЗЕРВНЫЙ')
    foreach($port in $arrayport)
    {
        $port = $snmpport
    }  
    $url = ("http://{0}:{1}/sys.xml" -f $ipaddr, $snmpport)
    Write-Output $url
}

Уточнение.
В выводе должно получится вот так:
http://10.10.10.10:4000/sys.xml
http://10.10.10.10:4010/sys.xml

http://10.10.10.11:4002/sys.xml
http://10.10.10.11:4013/sys.xml
http://10.10.10.11:4011/sys.xml
http://10.10.10.11:4014/sys.xml
 
http://10.10.10.12:4005/sys.xml
http://10.10.10.12:4008/sys.xml


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Нужна еще проверка, не являются ли значения для ключей UPS словарями if ($ports -is [System.Collections.IDictionary]). В зависимости от этого либо перебирать порты внутри вложенного словаря либо брать значение.
foreach($item in $station.Values)
{
    $ipaddr = $item.ip
    $arrayport = @($item.UPS1, $item.UPS2)
    foreach($ports in $arrayport)
    {
        if ($ports -is [System.Collections.IDictionary]){
            foreach($port in $ports.Values)
            {
                $url = ("http://{0}:{1}/sys.xml" -f $ipaddr, $port)
                Write-Output $url
            }
        } else {
                $url = ("http://{0}:{1}/sys.xml" -f $ipaddr, $ports)
                Write-Output $url
        }
        
    }  
}

http://10.10.10.10:4000/sys.xml
http://10.10.10.10:4010/sys.xml
http://10.10.10.11:4013/sys.xml
http://10.10.10.11:4002/sys.xml
http://10.10.10.11:4014/sys.xml
http://10.10.10.11:4011/sys.xml
http://10.10.10.12:4005/sys.xml
http://10.10.10.12:4008/sys.xml


Огромное человеческое СПАСИБО!
